# Fibonacci-like sequences mod $p$ where $a_{n+1}$ only really depends on $a_n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, finite-fields, fibonacci-numbers

Consider a prime $p$ and a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ satisfying $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Now, assume that each element of the sequence only really depends on the previous one. That is, assume there exists a function $f:\mathbb{F}_p\to\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ for all $n\ge 0$.

If $p\not\in\{2,5\}$ and $5$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ there are the obvious sequences
$$\left(c\left[\frac12+\frac12\sqrt5\right]^n\right)_{n\ge 0}\quad\text{and}\quad\left(c\left[\frac12-\frac12\sqrt5\right]^n\right)_{n\ge 0}$$
for $c\in\mathbb{F}_p$ any constant, but are there any others?

### Computational results by @Servaes

Let's call two Fibonacci-like sequences modulo $p$ *equivalent* if they can be turned into each other through shifting and multiplication by units, then any sequence where each element is a function of the previous and and which is not equivalent to
$$(0)_{n\ge 0},\quad (c^n)_{n\ge 0}$$
where $c^2=c+1$, is called *strange*.

@Servaes has shown through computation that the first few primes for which strange sequences exist are
$$199, 211, 233, 281, 421, 461, 521, 557, 859, 911.$$

### Own work

For any prime $p$ let $\pi(p)$ be the [Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) mod $p$ (so this is *not* the prime counting function)

**Claim:** Let $p$ be a prime, $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ a strange sequence. Then it has period $\pi(p)$.

**Proof:** Let $A=\{a_n:n\ge 0\}$ be the set of attained values and $f:A\to A$ the function which makes this sequence strange, in the sense that $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ for all $n\ge 0$. Clearly, $f$ is a bijection.

It is easily proved that, for all $a\in A$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$f^n(a)=F_{n-1}a+F_nf(a).$$
Let $m$ be the period of $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$, then clearly $m$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ for which $f^n=\operatorname{id}_A$. Thus, for all $a\in A$,
$$(1-F_{m-1})a=F_mf(a)$$
If $F_m\neq 0$ it follows that $f(a)=F_m^{-1}(1-F_{m-1})a$ and the sequence is equivalent to $\left(c^n\right)_{n\ge 0}$ where $c=F_m^{-1}(1-F_{m-1})$ satisfies $c^2=c+1$. This contradicts our assumption that the sequence is strange, so $F_m=0$.

Since the sequence is not the null sequence, we may take $a\in A$ non-zero and conclude that $F_{m-1}=1$. It follows that $\pi(p)\mid m$. Since
$$f^{\pi(p)}(a)=F_{\pi(p)-1}a+F_{\pi(p)}f(a)=F_{-1}a+F_0F(a)=a,$$
the opposite division relation holds as well and we are done.

**EDIT:** I asked a slightly more general version of this question on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371892/fibonacci-like-sequences-in-mathbbf-q-where-each-element-only-depends-on-th) and linked to this question, but forgot to link the Mathoverflow question here.

Comment: For $p=5$ the sequence $(2,1,3,4,2,1,\ldots)$ works. And of course the zero sequence works for any $p$. There are no other sequences (up to shifting) for $p\leq5$.

Comment: Also, except the zero sequence, no sequence can contain a $0$. Nor can it have $a_{n+1}=a_n$ for any $n$. Moreover, if $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ is such a sequence the so is $(ca_n)_{n\geq0}$ for any constant $c$. So without loss of generality $a_0=1$. This leaves $p-2$ initial values for $a_1$, for each $p$.

Comment: A computer search yields plenty of examples. For $p=11$:
$$(1, 4, 5, 9, 3, 1, 4,\ldots),\qquad (1, 8, 9, 6, 4, 10, 3, 2, 5, 7, 1, 8,\ldots),$$
and $2$ sequences for $p=19$, up to shifts, and $16$ sequences for $p=29$, up to shifts, etc.

Comment: @Servaes Note that, mod $11$, the roots of $X^2-X-1$ are $4$ and $8$, so the given sequences are exactly of the type I describe in my question.

Comment: @Servaes If it's easier to check whether any sequences exist, I suggest you look only at primes $p$ such that $5$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment; only $2$ sequences for $p=29$, also corresponding to the roots of $X^2-X-1$.

Comment: Some simple python code shows that the first primes for which there are not either $0$ or $2$ such sequences, up to multiplication by constants and shifting, are:
$$5,\ 199,\ 211,\ 233,\ 281,\ 421,\ 461,\ 521,\ 557,\ 859,\ 911.$$

Comment: @Servaes Interesting! Could you perhaps compute the starting two values of such a sequence mod $199$ which does not correspond to a root of $X^2-X-1$?

Comment: I'm still cleaning up the proof, but I believe that the period of any sequence not of the 'standard' types must be the Pisano period mod p.

Comment: For $p=199$ I found the starting values $a_0=1$ and $a_1$ is one of:
$$6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 32, 34, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 46, 48, 53, 54, 55, 57, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 67, 72, 77, 80, 81, 82, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 93, 96, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109, 110, 111, 114, 115, 117, 118, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 144, 147, 148, 149, 150, 152, 153, 155, 156, 159, 162, 163, 164, 165, 167, 169, 171, 172, 173, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 187, 189, 190, 193, 195, 196.$$

Comment: Quite surprisingly, it seems that the number of values for $a_1$ that yields such a sequence is either $1+\left(\tfrac{5}{p}\right)$, except for the primes I just listed, in which case the number of values for $a_1$ is huge!

Comment: For $p=211$ I get:
$$6,8,9,23,24,26,29,32,33,34,45,48,62,71,76,98,108,109,119,124,127, 128, 132, 133, 135, 137, 139, 146, 152, 156, 157, 158, 162, 166, 168, 169, 173, 177, 179, 181, 187, 195, 199, 208.$$
For $p=233$ I get:
$$7,9,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,23,24,27,30,31,33,34,36,39,42,43,47,49,50,51,53,55,56,61,62,65,67,69,72,73,76,81,82,84,87,92,96,97,98,101,102,104,106,108,110,113,114,120,121,124,126,128,130,132,133,136,137,138,142,147,150,152,153,158,161,162,165,167,169,172,173,178,179,181,183,184,185,187,191,192,195,198,200,201,203,204,207,210,211,214,215,216,217,219,220,221,222,225,227.$$

Comment: Also, I could not help but notice that these exceptional primes appear quite early on in the list of [Fibonacci primitive parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime#Fibonacci_primitive_part). I'm not sure I can imagine any sort of connection, certainly not at this hour.

Comment: @Servaes By your earlier comment, did you mean you did not find any such primes beyond $911$?

Comment: This is a really good question and if it doesn't get an answer in the next few days I'd strongly suggest asking it also on Mathoverflow with a link to this question.

Comment: @Mastrem Not at all, I just ran my code for $p<1000$ initially.

Comment: Yes, it stands to reason that small Pisano periods are needed for this to happen. Modulo $p=199$ the zeros of $x^2=x+1$ have multiplicative orders $22$ and $11$ (both in $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ as $\left(\dfrac5p\right)=1$). Modulo $p=233$ they are both of order $52$ in $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}^*$. Not clear what else is needed to guarantee no repetitions within a period.

Comment: Giving a bit of extra attention to this within [the Pearl Dive project](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive). Also editing my Pearl Dive "ad" in Meta.MathOverflow.

Comment: @OP Do you mind if I hijack some of this awesome work for a codegolf challenge? Credit will be attributed.

Comment: @DonThousand Sure, no problem.